# canLoad not firing & module still loading?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Hi I'm currently making an Angular application & I have 2 modules : a GuessModule & an AdminModule ; one of this module should always be loaded the GuessModule & the other one have a canLoad guard.

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/guest/guest.module').then(m => m.GuestModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    canLoad: [
      AuthGuard
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  }
];

// app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have a CoreModule with AuthGuard in it :

```
/// CoreModule forRoot called in app.module imports CoreModule.forRoot()
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
   return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        AuthGuard
      ],
    } as ModuleWithProviders;
  }
```

In my Auth Guard I have this :

```
canLoad(
   route: Route,
   segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   return false; // to test
}
```

But when I go on the route "/" I got my 2 modules loaded but only the GuessModule should be loaded & I don't know why I get both loaded ; the canLoad is not fired but the AdminModule is loaded.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you determining the module is loaded? Can you add a `console.log` statement in the constructor of `AdminModule` to verify?

Comment: It's simple I look into my network & I see a JS file named default~modules-admin-admin-module~modules-guest-guest-module.js being downloaded & when I remove the route admin it doesn't load.When I put a console.log into the AdminModule constructor I don't see it in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed the same thing when running in development mode, you see the module get loaded and think the canLoad guard is not preventing the module from getting loaded.  But if you make a production build using the command 'ng build --prod' and run this in your browser, you should find that the chunk associated with the module you're trying to guard indeed does not get loaded.  So the canLoad functionality seems to only work in production, not development.